# Вывод координаты элемента матрицы

Tags: python-3.x

Здравствуйте, как можно вывести или просто узнать саму координату(не значение в данной координате) элемента матрицы, для того чтоб работать уже непосредственно с ней(координатой элемента). к примеру по координате m1=[1,2] стоит стоит 1, но мы не знаем на самом деле по какой координате она находится, я хотим это узнать, показать на экране.

rol=5
col=6
m1=np.zeros((rol,col))
m1[1,2]=1

Comment: Добавьте к вопросу код, в котором вы работаете с матрицей.

Comment: непонятно, что именно вам не понятно. «узнать координаты» — пройти двойным циклом по элементам, сравнивая их значения с искомым. «вывести координаты» — например, оператором `print`.

Answer (score 0):

Что-нибудь такое:

```
import numpy as np

rol = 5
col = 6
m1 = np.zeros((rol, col))
m1[1, 2] = 1

value_to_find = 1
for i in range(rol):
    for j in range(col):
        if m1[i][j] == value_to_find:
            print('Нашли значение `{}` в позиции ({}, {})'.format(value_to_find, i, j))
```